# IIS 10 .Net8 RestAPI: The credentials you provide do not grant permission to view this directory or page

Tags: .net, rest, iis, .net-8.0

I have RestAPI .Net8 application. In that app I added `BasicAuthenticationHandler` that gave me possibility to add basic auth in app. I used database credentials to access to the rest API.

I want to publish my RestAPI to the IIS locally. I created new website, added path to the physical files. From VS I created new publish profile that create all files that I need it and push into the folder. On that folder I assign IIS web-site.

In Windows Features I enabled IIS manager and basic authentication. In IIS I enable basic authentication for my site. And all looks fine, but I can get access only to the test controller, for my controller that use base auth credentials I cannot get access. It doesn't work from web browser, or from postman query.

I 100% sure that it works, because I tested it while VS project was running. And my credentials that I use to the access to the web API works correctly! It's credentials that I added into database, the same credentials.

What's happening while I use web-browser: I have infinity loop with this window:

[image: Infinity loop with this window]

What's happening while I use postman query: HTTP 401.1 — Unauthorized error, and it's strange, I used the same credentials!

I also granted Full Control ACLs for IIS AppPool\MyPool:
`icacls D:\NetProjects\MySite\Publish\RestAPI /grant "IIS APPPOOL\MySite.com":(CI)(OI)(M)`

I was try to get access to my RestAPI after publish it in IIS locally.

What I have:

1. RestAPI with Basic Authentification created via `BasicAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>`;
   [image: Basic Auth]
2. IIS server with all eneble features Basic Authentification;
   [image: IIS]
3. Postman that sent query to the RestAPI;

Maybe I was missed something requirement? Because I read about adding new user into Windows Users Group, but it's strange, why I should add user to access to my RestAPI that using credentials from database?

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) for further guidance.